# Network Programming with Perl, by Stein - still relevant?

Tags: perl, sockets, networking, fork

*Network Programming with Perl* by Lincoln Stein is, IMO, a fantastic book, but the most recent edition (the only edition, in fact) is copyright 2001 and is contemporary with Perl 5.6.

I'm particularly interested in using **IO::Socket** and creating robust **fork**'ing (and sometimes **exec**'ing) servers.  I'm using Perl 5.14.

Does anyone with knowledge of the book, or with knowledge of Perl history, know what advances in Perl or CPAN have occurred since then that might make certain topics in this book obsolete or less optimal?

Comment: I don't know the book, but I can say that lower-level interface knowledge is still valuable even if you don't use those lower-level interfaces. Since the higher-level interfaces are built upon those interfaces, quirks in them become understandable and poorly documented function become clear (because they are usually poorly documented because they assume a knowledge of the underlying calls).

Comment: See also [Net::Server](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Net::Server)

Answer (score 6):

I haven't read the entire book, just took a peek at it some years ago (2 or 3).
Yes, it is excellent in regards of non-abstracted network access. Then, we have the [C10K problem](http://www.kegel.com/c10k.html). It spawned a bit different paradigm, that of asynchronous multiplexed I/O resources managed by single (or few) CPU cores.
So you can create very robust network servers using [AnyEvent](https://metacpan.org/module/AnyEvent) and/or [Coro](https://metacpan.org/module/Coro) ([see this quick intro](http://www.slideshare.net/miyagawa/asynchronous-programming-with-anyevent)).
Many servers are hybrid, actually: they multiplex external listeners and route calls to preforked servers (see, [Plack::Loader::Shotgun](https://metacpan.org/module/Plack::Loader::Shotgun) and [Mojolicious' hypnotoad](https://metacpan.org/module/Mojo::Server::Hypnotoad)).

**P.S. -** note that I am oversimplifying on purpose; unfortunately, I know no comprehensive guide to asynchronous Perl.

Comment: Good point about C10K.  (Fortunately, the application I'm building doesn't require that.)